# InputStream reading file and counting lines/words

Tags: java

I'm working on a project and I'm trying to count

1) The number of words.
2) The number of lines in a text file.

My problem is that I can't figure out how to detect when the file goes to the next line so I can increment lines correctly. Basically if next is not a space increment words and if next is a new line, increment lines. How would I do this? Thanks!

```
public static void readFile(Scanner f) {
  int words = 0;
  int lines = 0;
  while (f.hasNext()) {
     if (f.next().equals("\n")) {
        lines++;
     } else if (!(f.next().equals(" "))) {
        words++;
     }
  }

  System.out.println("Total number of words: " + words);
  System.out.println("Total number of lines: " + lines);
}
```

Comment: It seems like you tried to solve this problem with the code you posted. What's wrong with it? What happens when you run it?

Comment: The problem was that it would return the number of words in the file, but it always returned 0 lines. 

Enter the name of the file: DavidCopperfield.txt
Total number of words: 357839
Total number of lines: 0

I've checked off the answer and what nandsito said works perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```java
public static void readFile(Scanner f) {
    int words = 0;
    int lines = 0;
    while (f.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = f.nextLine();
        lines++;
        for (String token : line.split("\\s+")) {
            if (!token.isEmpty()) {
                words++;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Total number of words: " + words);
    System.out.println("Total number of lines: " + lines);
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly as is! Though I've never used the String token part before, thank you! Learned something new.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use InputStream? (Yes) It is better to use a BufferedReader with an InputStreamReader passed in so you can read the file line by line and increment while doing so.

```
numLines = 0;
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
        {
           numLines++;
           // process the line.
        }
    }
```

Then to count the words just split the string using a regular expression that finds whitespaces. `myStringArray = MyString.Split(MyRegexPattern);` will then return a `String[]` of all the words. Then all you do is `numWords += myStringArray.length();`

Comment: it will miscount empty lines and lines with spaces only

Comment: Your answer is basically what I told him lol I just didn't tell him to increment through the words and count.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
public static void readFile(Scanner f) {
  int words = 0;
  int lines = 0;
  while (f.hasNextLine()) {
         String line = f.nextLine();
         String[] arr = line.split("\\s");   
         words += arr.length;
         lines++;

  }

  System.out.println("Total number of words: " + words);
  System.out.println("Total number of lines: " + lines);
}
```

Comment: I just tried this and worked with it a bit and it keeps returning the lines and words with the exact same number.

Comment: Enter the name of the file: DavidCopperfield.txt
Total number of words: 357839
Total number of lines: 357839

Comment: Works now, though I believe it's throwing in extra words here and there. Total number of words: 367141
Total number of lines: 38588
 Number of lines is exact. However, the number of words I have no idea how many are really there... I used Microsoft word and other sources to count them and they always vary by 10,000~ words. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an InputStreamReader to create a bufferedreader which can read a file line by line:

```
int amountOfLines = 0;          
try {BufferedReader br = new   BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream))} catch (Exception e)  {e.printStackTrace();}
 String line; 
 while ((line = br.readLine()) != null{ 
     numLines++;
     // process the line. 
 }
```

You can then use the split(String) method to separate every part